# Displaying text from text file into boostrap modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I've created a modal inside my main page, and I use jQuery to get the data from the text file, I am able to successfully get the data from the text file and able to console log out the text file, but when I open my modal, the field was blank. May I know the reason why ??

Here is the code for getting the data from text file :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  jQuery.get('{% static 'css/legalNotice.txt' %}',function readFile(data)
  {
    $('#outputText').val(data);
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Here is the console log file, I can get the data
[image]

Here is the bootstrap modal code :

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="legalNotice" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="legalNoticeLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title col-md-11" id="legalNoticeLabel">TCA License</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close col-md-1" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 50px">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">
                <p id="outputText"></p>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="cancelButton" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I use a p tag to output the text that I get from the function , the id of the p tag is outputText, but when I open my modal, it was blank like this

[image]

Does anyone know where did I made a mistake ?? Why my modal is blank ? It shouldn't be.

Thanks in advance !! Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting the val attribute using $(selector).val() function , instead of this you have to set the inner html of paragraph tag for displaying data on the DOM.

hope it will help.

Comment: Yes, thank you, after I set the innerHTML , it works ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

JQuery's `.val()` function is for *retrieving* a nodes value, not for *setting* it. What you want is to use JQuery;s `.text()` function that can be used to set text on a node.

Replace your `$('#outputText').val(data);` to the following:

```
$('#outputText').text(data)
```

Comment: My apologies. I have fixed my answer and will keep it here for a JQuery solution

Comment: nvm is okay, actually I just put the getElementById and set the data as innerhtml then it works. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $('#legalNotice').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
             fetchFile();
          });
      });

function fetchFile(){
         jQuery.get('{% static 'css/legalNotice.txt' %}',function readFile(data)
          {
            $('#outputText').text("").text(data);
            //or
           $('#outputText').html("").html(data);    
          });

}
```

Comment: yes, I used Jquery. However, the same can also be implemented using plain javascript like : document.getElementById("outputText").innerHTML=data;